# class library using asp.net ComponentModel.Annotations causes errors

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Well so far asp.net 5 is really time wasting and aggravating, even for simple tasks.

I was trying to write a domain model for a new project using asp.net5, since thats where we are supposedly heading.

Writing simple enums worked fine UNTIL I wrote some classes that needed them and some of those properties needed ComponentModel Annotations.

So when I used the helper to add that reference WOW WTF

[image]

Of course once I take that dependency out of the project.json it reruns to normal. Obviously I need the Annotations, so how do you add them since clearly the automatic way VS2015 is doing it isn't right, thus creating all these errors. Well the answer, from a lot of googling, appears to be that the dependency is "System.ComponentModel": "4.0.0.0", and it gets added in the dnxcore50 dependencies NOT where VS added its dependency. BUT that doesnt work, the Annotations still err!

Comment: Did you install it through nugget? https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.ComponentModel.Annotations/

Comment: No, thru right click menu but I'll try adding via nuget

Comment: based on the versions of your dependencies it seems you are using a very old beta, I suggest [install the rc1 and tooling from here](https://get.asp.net/) then start again or update the versions of your dependencies

Answer (score 0):

The vNext web project has a dependency on Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc. Change this:

```
"dependencies": {
    "System.ComponentModel.Annotations": ""
},
to

"dependencies": {
     "Microsoft.DataAnnotations":  "" //use whatever latest version is
}
```

Comment: It's not an ,MVC project, it is just a domain class's library. I added the Microsft.DataAnnotations dependency but the [Key] [ForeignKey] a and [NotMapped] attributes are still not recognized. So I tried to use the fluent API, and even though I added the requisite EF7 dependencies and DBContext is fine it has no idea what a DbModelBuilder is